# libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException when building an OpenGL application using JAVA

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

Below is the full error message, the code is a demo from my teacher so I suppose it is correct.

2020-02-15 21:28:37.934 java[14142:330555] *** Assertion failure in +[NSUndoManager _endTopLevelGroupings], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/Foundation/Foundation-1454.90/Foundation/Misc.subproj/NSUndoManager.m:361
2020-02-15 21:28:37.935 java[14142:330555] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '+[NSUndoManager(NSInternal) _endTopLevelGroupings] is only safe to invoke on the main thread.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff37ff32db __exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff5f2a3c76 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff37ff9072 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 98
    3   Foundation                          0x00007fff3a122340 -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 193
    4   Foundation                          0x00007fff3a0b0f44 +[NSUndoManager(NSPrivate) _endTopLevelGroupings] + 469
    5   AppKit                              0x00007fff354fd96e -[NSApplication run] + 997
    6   libglfw.dylib                       0x000000012650ba85 libglfw.dylib + 68229
    7   libglfw.dylib                       0x0000000126505416 libglfw.dylib + 42006
    8   ???                                 0x00000001128fb950 0x0 + 4606376272
    9   ???                                 0x00000001128f5790 0x0 + 4606351248
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Comment: Can you add the code from your teacher, it may not be correct and fixing it may be part of your assignment. Also we're not really into solving homework problems.

Comment: Try changing the JDK version. It worked for me! Eclipse -> Preferences -> Java -> Installed JREs and add another JDK